# Set the minValue directly in a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is there a way to set a minValue directly in a `DateTimePicker` and not in a `DateTime`.
I use WPF and dotnet 4.0.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: MinValue for a datagird is 01/01/0001, and i would like the minvalue will be 12/31/2999.

Comment: Well create that `DateTime` object and assign it to the `MinDate` of the `DateTimePicker`

Comment: How set the minValue value of a dateTime ? Like this : DateTime myDate; myDate.minValue=12/31/2999

Answer (score 0):

this might be your answer.

```
 <DatePicker Grid.Row="2" DisplayDateStart="1/1/2013" DisplayDateEnd="5/10/2013" />
```

if not please provide more detaied question.